# Would this question about philosophy of Math be on-topic?

Tags: support, specific-question

There is a question on Math.SE :https://math.stackexchange.com/q/815718/103816 . It is put on hold there as off-topic. The question seems to be about the philosophy and history of Math. I flagged it to ask the mods for migrating it here on Philosophy.SE. But they refused and said, "*We only migrate questions that fit on the desired site*".

> So would it be on-topic here? If not then is there any other SE site where it can be on-topic?

Comment: It could use a little more development/focusing to be "optimally" on-topic for us

Comment: @JosephWeissman I am not the OP of that question. Can the question _as it is_ be on-topic. I need a firm stand of Philosophy.SE community on this because I want to give a reference of this meta-post to MSE mods.

Comment: Sorry, to be clear: it definitely does *not* seem on-topic to me as currently formulated

Comment: @JosephWeissman Thanks for the clarification. I just wanted to make it sure. I'd like to know if other users of Philosophy.SE also think the question will be off-topic.

Comment: Fair enough! :)

Comment: As worded I don't think it's a question yet... it would be more helpful if were asked as an interpretive question about the passage in Aristotle or about say the Kalaam cosmological argument rather than a generic I don't understand two concepts.

Comment: It seems like it asks a fairly clear and answerable question to me: 'what is an example of the distinction between potential and actual infinity?' (and somebody could answer with Achilles and the tortoise or something like that)

Comment: For what it's worth, not only did `they` refuse to migrate it, but I was the handling mod over there.